# launchoptions retuning nil while clicking on remove notification when app is killed in iOS 13 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Clicked on push notification when app was killed
    if let options = launchOptions,
        let userInfo = options[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    {
        // App was launched through a notification, execute some code here...
        Logger.log(message: "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:\(userInfo)")
        nofificationData = userInfo
    }
            
    return true
}
```

Please see the code I have implemented it didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but launchOptions always return nil. please advice.
Thanks